# Problem displaying multiple objects in modern OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math, vbo, vao

I'm trying to display two shapes in OpenGL.
First I got the vertices,uvs, normals,indices from an obj file and texture form DDS and stored them in an array of struct Shape.

Then I indexed the vertices, uvs, normals and indices for all the shapes in 4 respective array, also storing the number of total number of vertices, uvs , normals and indices in another vector.
Then I initialized the VBOs.

Then I creates vertex array objects for the two shapes and set them up giving respective VertexAttribPointer. (I think the problem is in this step)

Finally I bind the respective VAOs and display them but only one shape is being displayed.
Where exactly am I going wrong.

Code for VBOindexing :

```
std::vector<glm::vec4> elecount;
long long int endind = 0,endver=0,enduv=0,endnr=0;

std::vector<unsigned short> indices;
std::vector<glm::vec3> indexed_vertices;
std::vector<glm::vec2> indexed_uvs;
std::vector<glm::vec3> indexed_normals;
for (int i = 0;i < componentcount ;i++)
{
    endver = endind = enduv = endnr = 0;
    indexVBO(component[i].vertices, component[i].uvs, component[i].normals, indices, indexed_vertices, indexed_uvs, indexed_normals);
    endind = indices.size();
    endver = indexed_vertices.size();
    enduv = indexed_uvs.size();
    endnr = indexed_normals.size();
    elecount.push_back(glm::vec4(endver, enduv, endnr, endind));
}
```

Code for VBOs :

```
GLuint vertexbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexed_vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &indexed_vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLuint uvbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &uvbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexed_uvs.size() * sizeof(glm::vec2), &indexed_uvs[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLuint normalbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &normalbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexed_normals.size() * sizeof(glm::vec3), &indexed_normals[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLuint elementbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &elementbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned short), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Code for VAOs :

```
    GLuint CubeVertexArrayID, SphereVertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &CubeVertexArrayID);
glGenVertexArrays(1, &SphereVertexArrayID);

glBindVertexArray(CubeVertexArrayID);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementbuffer);

glBindVertexArray(SphereVertexArrayID);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void *)(sizeof(glm::vec3) * ((int)elecount[0][0])));
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)(sizeof(glm::vec2) * ((int)elecount[0][1])));
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalbuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)(sizeof(glm::vec3) * ((int)elecount[0][2])));
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementbuffer);
```

Code for displaying :

```
    glBindVertexArray(CubeVertexArrayID);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, component[0].Texture);
    glUniform1i(TextureID, 0);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,(int)elecount[0][3],GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,(void*)0);

    glm::mat4 ModelMatrix2 = glm::mat4(1.0);
    ModelMatrix2 = glm::translate(ModelMatrix2, glm::vec3(2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    glm::mat4 MVP2 = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix2;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP2[0][0]);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &ModelMatrix2[0][0]);
    glUseProgram(shaderProg);

    glBindVertexArray(SphereVertexArrayID);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, component[1].Texture);
    glUniform1i(TextureID, 0);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (int)(elecount[1][3]-elecount[0][3]), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,(void*)(sizeof(unsigned short) * ((int)elecount[0][3])));
```

Comment: What is the question? You said that there is a problem, but what doe not work?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Only one shape is being displayed when I call glDrawElement. I'll update the question in a sec.

Comment: @curs0r: what index does `indexVBO` push to `indices`?

Comment: @ybungalobill It pushes which indices to print, if two different indices were there which printed same vertices, it replaced them by a single index.

Comment: @curs0r: that wasn't the essanse of my question. Since my answer below worked for you it means that `indexVBO` calculates the indices incorrectly. Which is why you should have provided the code for that function.

Comment: @ybungalobill I think its working correctly because when i  use it with a single buffer, its giving correct output. I'm a beginner in OpenGL coding so i think my VAO concepts might be a bit messed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong in the code you posted, so it's hard to say for sure where's the problem. However my best guess is that `indexVBO` (that you didn't show) pushes the absolute indices within `indexed_*` arrays. Combined with the offset `glVertexAttribPointer` of `SphereVertexArrayID` this causes out-of-bound reads.

You could fix your `indexVBO` code. However, since both VAOs reference the same buffer, the simplest solution (and I would say, the correct solution) is to use a single VAO for both components. If my hypothesis is correct, it is as simple as changing the

```
glBindVertexArray(SphereVertexArrayID);
```

to

```
glBindVertexArray(CubeVertexArrayID);
```

when you're drawing the 2nd component. Then you can get rid of `SphereVertexArrayID` completely.

Comment: I did exactly this and it worked. I am planning to add multiple objects so I used different buffers. Changing it to a single buffer worked. Thanks @ybungalobill

Comment: @curs0r: It's best to use a single VAO when you can, even for multiple objects.